# Prove the series converges $\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \sqrt{\frac{k^2+1}{k^3-3}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Prove $\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{k^2+1}}{k^3-3}$ converges.

I was trying to find an easy comparison for an integral test, but not much luck.

Comment: This looks to be straightforwardly divergent.

Comment: The original question was not in $\LaTeX$: `sum sqrt(k^2+1)/(k^3-3) for k=2 to inf` It was not clear whether it was supposed to be this or $$\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{\sqrt{k^2+1}}{k^3-3}$$ The statement of the question leads me to think it was the latter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\sqrt {k^{2}+1} \leq k+1$ and $k^{3}-3 \geq \frac 1 2 k^{3}$ for all $k >1$. Can you complete the argument?

Answer (score 3):

It is easy to see that $\frac{k^2+1}{k^3-3} \ge \frac{1}{k^2}$ for $k \ge 2$, hence

$\sqrt{\frac{k^2+1}{k^3-3}} \ge \frac{1}{k}$ for $k \ge 2$.

Consequence: the series is divergent.